# Arithmetic operator inside column

Tags: sql, oracle

It looks so simple but i don't see any answer for it. Here is my question.

```
Table 
Col1, Col2
12, *24/100
8,*12*24/10
```

I need to to an arithmetic operation with `col1` and `col2` (ie. `12*24/100 = 2.88`) but oracle is processing as a string value and gives result as `'12*24/100'`

How to do an arithmetic operation where you have formula in one column and value in other column?

Comment: First of all is this oracle or sql server? Secondly, a DBMS is used to store and retrieve data. If you want it to calculate the contents of a varchar as a math formula you need dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sean lange.
Its an oracle db.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmlquery but I would have to think there's a better way.  Let's see what folks come up with.

```
SQL> with tbl(val, formula) as (
     select 12, '*24/100'   from dual union
     select 8,  '*12*24/10' from dual
   )
   select xmlquery(replace( val || formula, '/', ' div ')
          returning content).getNumberVal() as result
   from tbl;

    RESULT
----------
     230.4
      2.88

SQL>
```